# How can I call a custom function when the return button is pressed within a UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to debug a problem where pressing the return key doesn't trigger a text view change and as a result messes with my NSAttributedString inside of my UITextView. Whenever I press the return button my UITextView calculates the number of lines and for whatever reason thinks the image is only 1 line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a custom function with the `textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String)`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        textView.delegate = self
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        if text == "\n" {
            print("new line")
            // Call your custom function
        }

        return true
    }
```

Comment: I'm using a custom UITextView but even though it's a subclassed uitextview this method is never getting called. I can check when the textview changes like typing characters but not "\n"

Comment: I've tested it and it works for me. Have you set `textView.delegate = self`? @ggworean

Comment: Was in the wrong extension, thank you it's working now!